# how to login to ssh and download file with php script

Tags: php, cron

I have one digitalocean droplet where I have .sql backups. I want to be more sure that I have these backups to different server too so that if something happens to my original server where I store backups, i would have another server where I can get that backup. So, I decided to have another server which by cronjob every hour would login to my original server and get the sql file.

Question 1) where do I store my original server's public/private key in my another server? in windows locally, i store it at .ssh folder in Users/myusername folder. But now my servers are ubuntu both.

Question 2) to download the file, I know I can use scp. like this:

```
scp username@droplet_ip:/path/to/file /path/to/destination
```

put this in php script and make that php script executed by cron job. Problem is I also have set up passphare for my original server. so this command I showed here would need passphare and I am not sure how to do this because when cronjob starts executing it, i don't know how to provide passphare automatically.

When I run this command from local computer, I start enter and it asks me to provide passphare .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ssh2

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ssh2.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-recv.php

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

ssh2_scp_recv($connection, '/remote/filename', '/local/filename');
```

just go through the methods https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-auth-hostbased-file.php

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22, array('hostkey'=>'ssh-rsa'));

if (ssh2_auth_hostbased_file($connection, 'remoteusername', 'myhost.example.com',
                             '/usr/local/etc/hostkey_rsa.pub',
                             '/usr/local/etc/hostkey_rsa', 'secret',
                             'localusername')) {
  echo "Public Key Hostbased Authentication Successful\n";
} else {
  die('Public Key Hostbased Authentication Failed');
}
```